# Sequential function IO design-patterns in Python

Tags: python, function, design-patterns, program-entry-point

What is the name for this kind of design pattern in Python, where you sequentially call functions whose outputs
are inputs to the following functions?

Is this a good design-pattern? How can one avoid coupling between functions?

Example:

```py
def main():
    a = func_a(input_a)
    b = func_b(a)
    c = func_b(b)


def func_a(input_a):
    # Do stuff
    return output_a


def func_b(input_b):
    # Do stuff
    return output_b


def func_c(input_c):
    # Do stuff
    return output_c
   

if __name__ == ‘__main__’:
    main()
```